# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Here is my procedure in which i am filtering data bases of 4 parameters:

**start date, end date, hour and minute**.

When i filter data between to 2017-11-01 to 2017-11-30 (With in a month) its working fine but when i filtering data greater than 1 month like 2017-11-01 to 2017-12-10 then its giving me error as given below.

**Procedure**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE RentedTotalCars (
   startDate IN VARCHAR2,
   endDate IN VARCHAR2,
   control_time_hour IN VARCHAR2,
   control_time_min IN VARCHAR2,
   p_refcur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
dateDiffernce   INT;
v_no  INT;
l_query clob;
startDateInTimestamp TIMESTAMP;
endDateInTimestamp TIMESTAMP;
startDateInDate DATE;
endDateInDate DATE;
startDateText VARCHAR2(1200);
endDateText VARCHAR2(1200);
addedDate DATE;
addedTimestamp TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
   v_no := 0;
   startDateText := startDate || ' ' || control_time_hour || ':' || control_time_min || ':00';
   endDateText := endDate || ' ' || control_time_hour || ':' || control_time_min || ':00';
   startDateInTimestamp := TO_TIMESTAMP(startDateText, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
   endDateInTimestamp := TO_TIMESTAMP(endDateText, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
   startDateInDate := TO_DATE(startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
   endDateInDate := TO_DATE(endDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD');   

   dateDiffernce := endDateInDate - startDateInDate+1;
   l_query:= 'Select date1, codice, CODICE_NAZIONALE, sum(RentedCars)as RentedCars, sum(TotalCars) as TotalCars from (';
   while dateDiffernce > 0
   loop
   addedDate := startDateInDate+v_no;
   addedTimestamp := startDateInTimestamp+v_no;
   l_query:= l_query || ' (Select q2.date1, q2.CODICE, q2.CODICE_NAZIONALE, count(q2.id) as RentedCars, 0 as TotalCars from';
   l_query:= l_query || ' (Select ''' || addedDate || ''' as date1, m.ID_VEICOLO as id, m.ID_SEDE_USCITA, pv.ID_GRUPPO,s.CODICE, g.CODICE_NAZIONALE from';
   l_query:= l_query || ' (SELECT id_veicolo, ID_SEDE_USCITA from movimenti_auto where';
   l_query:= l_query || ' inizio <= ''' || addedTimestamp || ''' and';
   l_query:= l_query || ' fine >= ''' || addedTimestamp || ''' ) m';
   l_query:= l_query || ' left join parco_veicoli pv on m.id_veicolo = pv.id';
   l_query:= l_query || ' left join gruppi g on pv.ID_GRUPPO = g.id';
   l_query:= l_query || ' left join sedi s on m.ID_SEDE_USCITA = s.id';
   l_query:= l_query || ' where pv.IMPEGNATO = 1 ) q2';
   l_query:= l_query || ' group by CODICE_NAZIONALE, CODICE, date1)';
   l_query:= l_query || ' union all ';
   l_query:= l_query || ' (Select ''' || addedDate || ''' as date1, s.CODICE, g.CODICE_NAZIONALE, 0 as RentedCars, count(pv.id) TotalCars from Parco_veicoli pv';
   l_query:= l_query || ' left join gruppi g on pv.id_gruppo = g.id';
   l_query:= l_query || ' left join sedi s on pv.id_sede = s.id where';
   l_query:= l_query || ' (data_acq < ''' || addedDate || ''') and';
   l_query:= l_query || ' ((data_scadenza_contratto > ''' || addedDate || ''' or data_proroga_1 > ''' || addedDate || '''';
   l_query:= l_query || ' or data_proroga_2 > ''' || addedDate || ''')';
   l_query:= l_query || ' or data_vend > ''' || addedDate ||  ''')';
   l_query:= l_query || ' group by s.CODICE, g.CODICE_NAZIONALE )';
   if dateDiffernce > 1
   then
   l_query:= l_query || ' union all ';
   end if;

   v_no := v_no + 1;
   dateDiffernce := dateDiffernce-1;

   end loop;

   l_query:= l_query || ' ) q1';
   l_query:= l_query || ' group by Codice, Codice_nazionale, date1';
   l_query:= l_query || ' order by date1, Codice, Codice_nazionale';

   OPEN p_refcur FOR l_query;
END;
```

**Error**

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
>
> ORA-06512: at "MYRENT.RENTEDTOTALCARS", line 58
>
> ORA-06512: at line 13

My Line no 58 in procedure is:

**l_query:= l_query || ' (data_acq < ''' || addedDate || ''') and';**

Comment: can you print `dateDiffernce` variable in both the case i guess `dateDiffernce := endDateInDate - startDateInDate+1;` this is the problematic line

Comment: @smn_onrocks in which both cases?

Comment: `2017-11-01 to 2017-11-30 ` and `2017-11-01 to 2017-11-10` mean where u r getting error and not error

Comment: Don't `OPEN` it; `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_query)` so that you'd see how the query looks like. Try to execute it. You'll, hopefully, see what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Littlefoot i applied DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_query) and commented open cursor. Then i found exception coming before DBMS means while creation of query. its not printing l_query.So now what can i do in this?
Problem is in this line l_query:= l_query || ' (data_acq < ''' || addedDate || ''') and';

Comment: @smn_onrocks i edited my dates in question. I am getting error at 2017-11-01 to 2017-12-10 when date range is greater than 1 month.

Comment: I am confused by your line counting. How many lines has the whole code block in your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I meant: I commented the OUT parameter as well as OPEN statement, and included DBMS_OUTPUT.

```
SQL> create or replace PROCEDURE RentedTotalCars (
  2     startDate IN VARCHAR2,
  3     endDate IN VARCHAR2,
  4     control_time_hour IN VARCHAR2,
  5     control_time_min IN VARCHAR2
  6     --,    p_refcur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  7  )
  8  IS
  9    dateDiffernce   INT;
 10    v_no  INT;
 11    l_query varchar2(10000);
 12    startDateInTimestamp TIMESTAMP;
 13    endDateInTimestamp TIMESTAMP;
 14    startDateInDate DATE;
 15    endDateInDate DATE;
 16    startDateText VARCHAR2(1200);
 17    endDateText VARCHAR2(1200);
 18    addedDate DATE;
 19    addedTimestamp TIMESTAMP;
 20  BEGIN
 21     v_no := 0;
 22     startDateText := startDate || ' ' || control_time_hour || ':' || control_time_min || ':00';
 23     endDateText := endDate || ' ' || control_time_hour || ':' || control_time_min || ':00';
 24     startDateInTimestamp := TO_TIMESTAMP(startDateText, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
 25     endDateInTimestamp := TO_TIMESTAMP(endDateText, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
 26     startDateInDate := TO_DATE(startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
 27     endDateInDate := TO_DATE(endDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
 28
 29     dateDiffernce := endDateInDate - startDateInDate+1;
 30     l_query:= 'Select date1, codice, CODICE_NAZIONALE, sum(RentedCars)as RentedCars, sum(TotalCars) as TotalCars from (';
 31     while dateDiffernce > 0
 32     loop
 33     addedDate := startDateInDate+v_no;
 34     addedTimestamp := startDateInTimestamp+v_no;
 35     l_query:= l_query || ' (Select q2.date1, q2.CODICE, q2.CODICE_NAZIONALE, count(q2.id) as RentedCars, 0 as TotalCars from';
 36     l_query:= l_query || ' (Select ''' || addedDate || ''' as date1, m.ID_VEICOLO as id, m.ID_SEDE_USCITA, pv.ID_GRUPPO,s.CODICE, g.CODICE_NAZIONALE from';
 37     l_query:= l_query || ' (SELECT id_veicolo, ID_SEDE_USCITA from movimenti_auto where';
 38     l_query:= l_query || ' inizio <= ''' || addedTimestamp || ''' and';
 39     l_query:= l_query || ' fine >= ''' || addedTimestamp || ''' ) m';
 40     l_query:= l_query || ' left join parco_veicoli pv on m.id_veicolo = pv.id';
 41     l_query:= l_query || ' left join gruppi g on pv.ID_GRUPPO = g.id';
 42     l_query:= l_query || ' left join sedi s on m.ID_SEDE_USCITA = s.id';
 43     l_query:= l_query || ' where pv.IMPEGNATO = 1 ) q2';
 44     l_query:= l_query || ' group by CODICE_NAZIONALE, CODICE, date1)';
 45     l_query:= l_query || ' union all ';
 46     l_query:= l_query || ' (Select ''' || addedDate || ''' as date1, s.CODICE, g.CODICE_NAZIONALE, 0 as RentedCars, count(pv.id) TotalCars from Parco_veicoli pv';
 47     l_query:= l_query || ' left join gruppi g on pv.id_gruppo = g.id';
 48     l_query:= l_query || ' left join sedi s on pv.id_sede = s.id where';
 49     l_query:= l_query || ' (data_acq < ''' || addedDate || ''') and';
 50     l_query:= l_query || ' ((data_scadenza_contratto > ''' || addedDate || ''' or data_proroga_1 > ''' || addedDate || '''';
 51     l_query:= l_query || ' or data_proroga_2 > ''' || addedDate || ''')';
 52     l_query:= l_query || ' or data_vend > ''' || addedDate ||  ''')';
 53     l_query:= l_query || ' group by s.CODICE, g.CODICE_NAZIONALE )';
 54     if dateDiffernce > 1
 55     then
 56     l_query:= l_query || ' union all ';
 57     end if;
 58
 59     v_no := v_no + 1;
 60     dateDiffernce := dateDiffernce-1;
 61
 62     end loop;
 63
 64     l_query:= l_query || ' ) q1';
 65     l_query:= l_query || ' group by Codice, Codice_nazionale, date1';
 66     l_query:= l_query || ' order by date1, Codice, Codice_nazionale';
 67
 68     --   OPEN p_refcur FOR l_query;
 69     dbms_output.put_line(l_query);
 70  END;
 71  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> exec rentedtotalcars('2018-02-15', '2018-02-15', '15', '20');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

As you can see, the procedure was successfully created and executed. The result of DBMS_OUTPUT - in my database - looks like this:

```
  SELECT date1,
         codice,
         CODICE_NAZIONALE,
         SUM (RentedCars) AS RentedCars,
         SUM (TotalCars) AS TotalCars
    FROM ( (  SELECT q2.date1,
                     q2.CODICE,
                     q2.CODICE_NAZIONALE,
                     COUNT (q2.id) AS RentedCars,
                     0 AS TotalCars
                FROM (SELECT '15.02.18' AS date1,
                             m.ID_VEICOLO AS id,
                             m.ID_SEDE_USCITA,
                             pv.ID_GRUPPO,
                             s.CODICE,
                             g.CODICE_NAZIONALE
                        FROM (SELECT id_veicolo, ID_SEDE_USCITA
                                FROM movimenti_auto
                               WHERE     inizio <= '15.02.18 15:20:00,000000'
                                     AND fine >= '15.02.18 15:20:00,000000') m
                             LEFT JOIN parco_veicoli pv ON m.id_veicolo = pv.id
                             LEFT JOIN gruppi g ON pv.ID_GRUPPO = g.id
                             LEFT JOIN sedi s ON m.ID_SEDE_USCITA = s.id
                       WHERE pv.IMPEGNATO = 1) q2
            GROUP BY CODICE_NAZIONALE, CODICE, date1)
          UNION ALL
          (  SELECT '15.02.18' AS date1,
                    s.CODICE,
                    g.CODICE_NAZIONALE,
                    0 AS RentedCars,
                    COUNT (pv.id) TotalCars
               FROM Parco_veicoli pv
                    LEFT JOIN gruppi g ON pv.id_gruppo = g.id
                    LEFT JOIN sedi s ON pv.id_sede = s.id
              WHERE     (data_acq < '15.02.18')
                    AND (   (   data_scadenza_contratto > '15.02.18'
                             OR data_proroga_1 > '15.02.18'
                             OR data_proroga_2 > '15.02.18')
                         OR data_vend > '15.02.18')
           GROUP BY s.CODICE, g.CODICE_NAZIONALE)) q1
GROUP BY Codice, Codice_nazionale, date1
ORDER BY date1, Codice, Codice_nazionale
```

I can't run it as I don't have your tables, but you might try to do that. Note DATE format - it is DD.MM.YY. Maybe you'll need to *convert* it to a valid date format - that depends on your NLS settings. The *safest* way would be to explicitly make it a DATE literal (which is always `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'`), or use TO_DATE with appropriate format mask.